# Call ACF field in PHP function

Tags: php, wordpress, function, advanced-custom-fields

I have this PHP function to add a scheduled banner to my website. I want to make it workable with ACF fields.

The function:

```
function holiday_site_banner() {
    
    $from_time = new DateTime( 'get_field('banner_start_date')' );
    $to_time = new DateTime( 'get_field('banner_end_date')' );

    if ( new DateTime() > $from_time && new DateTime() < $to_time ) {
        ?><div class="site-banner">
            <span>
                <strong style="">&#9432; LET OP:</strong> <?php get_field('banner_message')?>
            </span>
        </div><?php
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'holiday_site_banner' );
```

I tried to use the `get_field` for implementing the ACF values in `$from_time` and `$to_time` but it doens't work.
I set the ACF field for this as a datepicker with output `Y-m-d H:i`, named `[banner_start_date]` and `[banner_end_date]`.

Then I also have a ACF textarea field named `[banner_message]` to place in between the `<span>`tags as you can see which also not works.

The ACF fields are added to a custom option page created with this code:

```
if( function_exists('acf_add_options_page') ) {
    
    acf_add_options_page(array(
        'page_title'    => 'DWD Vakantiesluiting',
        'menu_title'    => 'DWD Vakantie',
        'menu_slug'     => 'dwd-vakantiesluiting',
        'capability'    => 'edit_posts',
        'icon_url'      => 'dashicons-lock',
        'redirect'      => true,
        'updated_message' => __("Vakantiemodus ingesteld", 'acf'),
    ));
    
}
```

I modified the code to this but that still doesn't work:

```
function scheduled_site_banner() {
    // Get the start and end date values from ACF fields
    $start_date = get_field('banner_start_date', 'option');
    $end_date = get_field('banner_end_date', 'option');
    $banner_message = get_field('banner_message', 'option');

    // Create DateTime objects for the start and end date
    $start_time = new DateTime($start_date);
    $end_time = new DateTime($end_date);

    // Format the start and end date
    $formatted_start_date = date("F j, Y",strtotime($start_date));
    $formatted_end_date = date("F j, Y",strtotime($end_date));

    // Check if the current date and time falls between the start and end dates
    if ( new DateTime() > $start_time && new DateTime() < $end_time ) {
        ?>
        <div class="site-banner">
            <span>
                <strong>Important Notice:</strong> <?php echo $banner_message; ?>  Our site-wide banner is scheduled to display from <?php echo $formatted_start_date ?> to <?php echo $formatted_end_date ?>
            </span>
        </div>
        <?php
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'scheduled_site_banner' );
```

Also using double quotations marks in `// Get the start and end date values from ACF fields` doesn't work.

Is there anyone who could help me with this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please show us _how exactly_ you tried to use `get_field`, instead of just telling us _that_ you tried to use it.

Comment: Sorry, I added it to the code.

Comment: In this form, it would not even execute, your use of single quotes there causes a parse error.

Comment: I changed the single quotes to double quotation marks and that executes the code, but unfortunately it doesn't work.

Comment: _Where_ did you actually store these values? Since you did not specify a post ID, this will always look for the field under the ID of the current post.

Comment: I create a custom option page for the fields. I added that code to the question.

Comment: Then you need to pass `'option'` as second parameter for `get_field`, so that it knows that you want to fetch this value from your options page, and not the current post. https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/options-pa

Comment: I did that and also modified the code, but it still doesn't work. It gives me a Critical Error on the website.

Comment: Then enable WP debug mode and check the error log, to find out the reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it done, thanks for the help. The problem was the date format among some other things. I also added `Europe/Amsterdam` Timezone.

This is the correct code:

```
function scheduled_site_banner() {
    // Get the start and end date values from ACF fields
    $start_date = get_field("banner_start_date", "option");
    $end_date = get_field("banner_end_date", "option");
    $banner_message = get_field("banner_message", "option");

    // Create DateTime objects for the start and end date and set Amsterdam timezone
    $start_time = DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-m-d H:i:s", $start_date, new DateTimeZone('Europe/Amsterdam'));
    $end_time = DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-m-d H:i:s", $end_date, new DateTimeZone('Europe/Amsterdam'));

    if($start_time === false || $end_time === false) {
        // date is not in correct format
        return;
    }

    // Check if the current date and time falls between the start and end dates
    if ( new DateTime('Europe/Amsterdam') > $start_time && new DateTime('Europe/Amsterdam') < $end_time ) {
        ?>
        <div class="site-banner">
            <span>
                <strong>Important:</strong> <?php echo $banner_message; ?>
            </span>
        </div>
        <?php
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'scheduled_site_banner' );
add_filter('acf/format_value', 'do_shortcode');
```

I also added 2 shortcodes which can be used in the message to display the start and enddates which are set in the acf fields. I used this code for that:

```
function register_acf_shortcodes() {
   add_shortcode('begin_vakantie', 'acf_banner_start_date_shortcode');
   add_shortcode('einde_vakantie', 'acf_banner_end_date_shortcode');
}
add_action( 'init', 'register_acf_shortcodes');

function acf_banner_start_date_shortcode() {
   $start_date = get_field('banner_start_date', 'option');
   return date('d-m-Y', strtotime($start_date));
}

function acf_banner_end_date_shortcode() {
   $end_date = get_field('banner_end_date', 'option');
   return date('d-m-Y', strtotime($end_date));
}
```

And added this filter to the `function scheduled_site_banner()` as you can see:

`add_filter('acf/format_value', 'do_shortcode');`

Last but not least I used this CSS for styling the banner and positioned it at the bottom of the page:

```
.site-banner {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #cf2e2e;
    padding: 1em;
    z-index: 99999;
    text-align: center;
      color: #ffffff;
}
```